# Qiskit - Renormalize the qubit after measurement

Tags: programming, qiskit

I have a 2 qubits system, maximally entangled, and I performed measurement on one of the qubit.

```
q = QuantumRegister(2)
c = ClassicalRegister(1)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
###create Bell State Qubit########
qc.h(q[1])
qc.cx(q[1],q[0])
### Perform Measurement ##########
qc.measure(q[0],c)
job = execute(qc,simulator,shots = 1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc)
print("\nTotal count for 0 and 1 are:",counts)
```

Before measurement, the state of the 2 qubit is $|00\rangle+|11\rangle/\sqrt{2}$. After obtaining the measurement result, I measured another qubit. I expected the 2nd qubit to collapse to either 1 of the 2 states($|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$) after measurement, but the result shows it is still in the superposition state. How do I renormalise the qubit state after measurement?

```
qc.measure(q[1],c)
job = execute(qc,simulator,shots=1000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(qc)
print("\n Total count for 0 and 1 are:,counts")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you think is the problem here.  You measure Qubit 0 and you should see 50% 0s and 50% 1s.  You rerun the simulator and measure Qubit 1 instead and are still seeing the same results.  These are new runs of the simulator.  They're not remembering what happened the last time you ran it.

Comment: Also note that if you measure both bits in the same run after entangling them.  You are guaranteed to get 00 or 11 in the classical registers.  The value of a qubit after reading it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the simulator, so adding a `reset` on the qubit you want to renormalize would work. The `reset` operation sets a qubit back to the ground state, $|0\rangle$. You would call this like any other operation: `circuit.reset(<qubits>)`. *Note: This will not work on the real devices.*

If you think it is still in superposition after the measurement, applying another H-Gate would fix that as well.

However, if you plan to continue using the simulator, applying the `reset` might be the better option as you will always be sure, no matter what, that that qubit is back in the $|0\rangle$ state.

Comment: Conditional reset is supported by IBMQ devices now https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/manage/systems/reset/backend_reset .